# How to design an API wrapper with bulky operations on domain object? (Need guidance)

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

I need some guidance in designing an API wrapper for my backend APIs. I have tried to keep it as specific as possible.

Context: We have a project which supports certain file operations like edit, create, merge etc. All the services are exposed as rest APIs. Now I have to create an API wrapper over this (client library) in Java. I've been reading about DDD and trying to approach the problem using that.

As per my thinking, the core object in my project would be File, along with some minor DTOs for talking to the backend. Edit, create, merge will be the verbs here acting on my domain object. I want to make it as easy as possible for the external developer to integrate the API. I would like the design to be something like that

For Creating a file : File.create() For editing : File.edit() Same for other operations Also, I want to have the capability of chaining operations (along the lines of fluent interfaces) for readability

For. eg. if you want to create a file and then convert it, it should be something like : File.create().convert(Required params)

My problem is each of the operation is bulky and async. I don't wanna write all the async error handling logic in the File class. Chaining the methods like above wont be easy as well if they return CompletableFuture objects, and this will be harder to maintain.

Question: What is a better way of solving this problem?

I am not looking for a spoonfed design. I just want to be guided to a design approach which fits the scenario. Feel free to point if I am understanding DDD wrong.

Comment: You should probably try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Done. I've also edited the question.

Comment: I think you cannot spare the work, you need to solve error handling by all those futures. The other option to have sync requests, which I guess you don't want to.  I don't know Java good enough, but if you have async-await, then you can easily handle async errors with that. I don't like fluent interfaces and chaining, I don't think it makes the code more readable. As Voice wrote these are infrastructure services in your client from DDD perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly: your domain model is responsible for bookkeeping.  The effects on the state of the filesystem are implemented in your infrastructure layer, and you send the results back to the bookkeeper.